# Ruby on Rails : rails generate controller does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby and rails and I am having a problem with generating controllers.

Some context :

```
$ rails -v
Rails 4.1.1
```

App is created correctly :

```
$ rails new test_app
      create
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
[...]
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
* bin/rake: spring inserted
* bin/rails: spring inserted
```

Server runs fine :

```
$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-06-07 11:12:20] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-06-07 11:12:20] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2014-02-24) [x86_64-cygwin]
[2014-06-07 11:12:20] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3340 port=3000
```

I can browse the default page, but then when I try to go to the next step, it's failing :

```
$ rails generate controller welcome index
```

Nothing happens and the files are not generated. There is not output at all so I don't know where I should look to fix the issue.

I already tried creating a fresh new app and reinstalling rails, but this doesn't help.

Comment: did you write that command in a separate tab or in the same tab but after closing the server?

Comment: As I am seeing the `$` symbol before the `rails gene..` command, I didn't guess about the mistake. But it can be ......

Comment: Do you have ActiveRecord enabled? Or maybe you have a custom generator called 'controller' created by accident?

Comment: @StefanHagen How to check if it is enabled or not ?

Comment: Yes it is a separate tab in the app folder.

The $ is just the cygwin command prompt.

I have seen people having a problem with custom generator, but I have no clue how I can see if I have one.

(sorry for the half reply, pressing enter sends the reply right away :-/)

Comment: no output? it just goes back to outputting `$`?

Comment: Are you in the correct directory when you run rails generate?

Comment: @silk Are you trying to run the `rails g..` from the same console, where you have started the *webrick* before stopping it or from the different console ?

Comment: Well it's only off if you manually did it yourself. In `config/application.rb` there should be a line that says `require rails/all` If you have replaced that manually with other stuff, it could be disabled.

Comment: sevenseacat yes no output at all.

StefanHagen I have tried to run rails new test_app and then generate the controller, same error. So I didn't touch anything there.

PS : It DID work yesterday when I first tried.

Comment: @silk In browser what *url* are hitting ? It seems the controller already created..

Comment: @ArupRakshit > no, not the same. It's another cygwin instance. Is it important ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I am browsing the default URL http://localhost:3000

Comment: output your rake routes

Comment: Can you try `./script/rails generate controller ..` ?

Comment: I will be away from my computer until tomorrow night, sorry. I didn't expect answers to come so fast.

Comment: @ArupRakshit OK so I tried this, and this is what I got : `$ ./script/rails generate controller welcome index
-bash: ./script/rails: No such file or directory`

Comment: @SahilGrover : This is what I get : `$ rake routes
You don't have any routes defined!

Please add some routes in config/routes.rb.`

Comment: try creating some scaffold  / model , just in case to test whether your `controller` `generator` is not working or `none of the generators` are working.

Comment: @SahilGrover none of them seem to work. Even `rails generate -h` does nothing.

Comment: if using rvm try reinstaling ruby and rails. thats all I can suggest

Answer (score 42):

Try to run

```
spring stop
```

rails generate may not work because spring is already running.

Comment: My surprise violated the principle of least surprise. I was having a good time following [the guide here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). I thought I would practice some more by deleting my project directory and start over when `bin/rails generate controller welcome index` resulted in no output and no file controller generation. That led me to this post. `spring stop` fixed the issue. Now I have to google `spring stop` so this will no longer surprise me.

Comment: This is the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on my Windows machine while trying to run `rails generate controller Users new`.

First,  make sure your spring is not running. Stop it with `spring stop`

If it did not help THEN:

1. Go to your Gemfile and comment out next two lines : `gem 'spring'
   and gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'`
2. In your terminal, run: `bundle update`

Answer (score 1):

I ran `spring stop` and it said that it was not running.

Then I did a `bundle install` and now it worked..

Answer (score 0):

I am using rails 6 and also worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the correct folder and not the environment, e.g. `~/environment/railsproject`.

I got the error and I had forgotten to `cd railsproject`.

The 'spring' and 'spring-watcher-listen' gems are still installed.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. When I aborted with ctl-c, I got:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/run.rb:54:in `gets': Interrupt
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/run.rb:54:in `verify_server_version'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/run.rb:25:in `call'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:23:in `call'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/share/yapo/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

So my guess as that the problem was somewhere in spring. I commented the line with spring in the Gemfile, ran `bundle update` and voila. Hope that works for you, too.

Maybe someone with a little bit more experience with ruby knows wether this is some problem in my/our configuration, or a bug?