# Issues generating controllers with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a Rails application successfully. My page loads on localhost:3000 without problem. When I run

```
rails generate controller demo index
```

it returns

```
sweet$ rails generate controller demo index
   identical  app/controllers/demo_controller.rb
       route  get 'demo/index'
      invoke  erb
       exist    app/views/demo
   identical    app/views/demo/index.html.erb
      invoke  test_unit
   identical    test/controllers/demo_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
   identical    app/helpers/demo_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      invoke  assets
      invoke    js
   identical      app/assets/javascripts/demo.js
      invoke    css
   identical      app/assets/stylesheets/demo.css
```

But it's not creating those files.  I checked the directory, and the files don't exist in those directories.
Here is the directory I'm in:

```
sweet$ pwd
/Users/sweet/dev/simple_cms
```

which is my app root.

I tried deleting the entire directory and recreating the app three times.  I killed all databases in MySQL via the root user. I ran `bundle install`. The app created successfully each time.

Does anyone know where Rails stores its logic for checking if a file exists or not when generating controllers/views?

Comment: The files are already there. What is exactly the problem? On a mac console you might want to exit that directory and ```cd``` into it again if you have deleted the directory before.

Comment: the files WEREN'T there was the issue but it was still reporting that they were.  Check my answer for details

Answer (score 2):

I commented out "spring" in the Gemfile, then ran

```
bundle update
bundle install
```

and retried making the controller, and it worked.

It must have been running the original application I had deleted long enough to "make it run faster".

"[Ruby on Rails : rails generate controller does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096262/ruby-on-rails-rails-generate-controller-does-not-work)" actually had the answer but my symptom was a bit different in that I was getting output.

Comment: If it was just a spring related, instead of updating all your gems, just do `bundle exec spring stop` and then re-run the generator.