# Rails doesn't generate controller with the command "rails generate controller Welcome index"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am fairly new to programming in Ruby on Rails. I am following the instructions on the Rails guide, but I am stuck at the this step `$ bin/rails generate controller Welcome index` in section [4.2](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

I have tried running the command `spring stop` as suggested by Timberlake in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31088232/5158845), but it is still not working, Rails just does not create the files and the route for me as stated in section [4.2](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

Comment: What is the output of the command `$ bin/rails generate controller Welcome index`?

Comment: what version of rails are you running? Type `rails -v` in the project directory

Comment: @StefanLyew, so when I am in the `bin` directory, I run the command `rails generate controller Welcome index`, the terminal just prompts me to write the next command without doing anything. Based on the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), It's supposed to output `create  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb
 route  get 'welcome/index'
invoke  erb
create    app/views/welcome
create    app/views/welcome/index.html.erb
invoke  test_unit
create    test/controllers/welcome_controller_test.rb
invoke  helper
create    app/helpers/welcome_helper.rb....`

Comment: @CdotStrifeVII my rails version is `Rails 5.0.0.1`

Comment: Another thing that I am concerned about, when the instruction asks me to run command `bin/rails generate controller Welcome index`, do I `cd` to the `bin` directory of the project and run `rails generate controller Welcome index` or do I run`bin/rails generate controller Welcome index` in the project root directory?

Comment: you should run this command in project's root directory

Comment: what's the output of `ls app/controllers` if you run it in project's root folder?

Comment: So do I run `rails generate controller Welcome index` or `bin/rails generate controller Welcome index` in the project's root directory?

Comment: @m.silenus running `ls app/controllers` gives me `application_controller.rb concerns`

Comment: @JeffreyYong You can use both of these commands. The second one `bin/rails generate` only makes sure  that the correct rails version your project use gets executed in case there's another 'rails' command in your PATH of different version.

Comment: have you used bundler, and `bundle install` command to install gems? You can also try executing `bundle exec rails generate controller Welcome index` in project's root

Comment: @m.silenus Yea, I have used bundle install before. I run the command 'bundle exec rails generate controller Welcome index' but still not working. :/

Comment: @JeffreyYong does `bin/rails generate -h` output anything for you? (to be clear, it should be run from the project's root directory)